# Numpy Vectorization for Nested 'for' loop

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I was trying to write a program which plots level set for any given function.

```python
rmin = -5.0
rmax = 5.0
c = 4.0
x = np.arange(rmin,rmax,0.1)
y = np.arange(rmin,rmax,0.1)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
f = lambda x,y: y**2.0 - 4*x
realplots = []
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        if abs(f(x[i,j],y[i,j])-c)< 1e-4:
            realplots.append([x[i,j],y[i,j]])`
```

But it being a nested for loop, is taking lot of time. Any help in vectorizing the above code/new method of plotting level set is highly appreciated.(Note: The function 'f' will be changed at the time of running.So, the vectorization must be done without considering the function's properties)

I tried vectorizing through
`ans = np.where(abs(f(x,y)-c)<1e-4,np.array([x,y]),[0,0])`
but it was giving me `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,100) (2,100,100) (2,)` 
I was adding `[0,0]` as an escape from `else` condition in np.where which is indeed wrong.

Comment: Have you looked up `broadcasting` in numpy docs?  That's going to be the key to solving this.  `abs(f(x,y)-c)<1e-4` is a (100,100) array, mask.  Do you understand why?  That broadcasts fine with the (2,100,100) term.  Now you just have to create another term that is (2,100,100) or (2,1,1) shape.

Comment: With this `where`, the third argument isn't an 'escape'.  It's an 'else' value.

Answer (score 2):

Since you get the values rather than the indexes, you don't really need `np.where`.

You can directly use the mask to index `x` and `y`, look at the ["Boolean array indexing"](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) section of the documentation.

It is straightforward:

```py
def vectorized(x, y, c, f, threshold):
    mask = np.abs(f(x, y) - c) < threshold
    x, y = x[mask], y[mask]
    return np.stack([x, y], axis=-1)
```

Your function for reference:

```py
def op(x, y, c, f, threshold):
    res = []
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[1]):
            if abs(f(x[i, j], y[i, j]) - c) < threshold:
                res.append([x[i, j], y[i, j]])
    return res
```

Tests:

```py
rmin, rmax = -5.0, +5.0
c = 4.0
threshold = 1e-4

x = np.arange(rmin, rmax, 0.1)
y = np.arange(rmin, rmax, 0.1)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

f = lambda x, y: y**2 - 4 * x

res_op = op(x, y, c, f, threshold)
res_vec = vectorized(x, y, c, f, threshold)

assert np.allclose(res_op, res_vec)
```

Comment: Is this really better than the (working] `where`?

Comment: Since indices or not needed it seems like `np.where` is just an useless extra step.